# 404 not found when serving angular app with http-server

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to use ng build to be able to deploy my application in production with 'http-server'.

So I ran ng build and then served the app with http-server. Everything looks fine after I login and I can access every page. But when I refresh the page or click in the browser's URL bar and hit enter I'm getting a '404 Not Found'.

I'm not having this problem when serving my app with 'npm start' (ng serve).

Comment: Referenced issue solves slightly different question. I use this for given issue: [angular-http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-server). But should not be used for production.
> A simple dev-server designed for Single Page App (SPA) developers. angular-http-server is not, and makes no claims to be, a production server.